# How to deal with unfeasible individuals in Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm trying to optimize a thermal power plant in a thermoeconomic way using Genetic Algorithms. Creating population gets me with a lot of unfeasible Individuals (e.g: ValueErros, TypeError etc.). I tried to use Penalty Functions, but the GA get stucked in first populations with a feasible Individual fitness and it doesn't evolve. There's any other way to deal with it?

I will be grateful if anyone can help me
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow such individuals to get part of the population. It will slow down your convergence but you will garantee that solutions found are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into **Diversity Control**.

In theory, invalid individuals may contain advantageous/valid pieces of code, and discarding them just because they have a bug is wasteful. In diversity control, your population is grouped into different species based on similarity metric (for tree structures it's usually edit distance), then the fitness of each individual is "shared" with other members of the group. In such a case `fitness = performance/group_size`. This is usually done to prevent premature convergence and to widen the exploration.

By combining your penalty function with diversity control, if the group of valid individuals becomes too numerous, fitness within that group will go down, and the groups that throw errors yet are less numerous will become more competitive, carrying the potentially valuable material forward.

Finally something like the rank-based selection should make the search insensitive to outliers, so when your top dog is 200% better than the other ones, it won't be selected all the time.